# Inheritance of Content Types in a Single Feature

Tags: visual-studio, content-type, feature-activation

I am having the same issue as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699451/240372 yet the solution does not work for me.

The ID's for my Content Types are the following

```
A   0x01080100B98211051B3409DB40D35D1515D2AB36
B   0x01080100B98211051B3409DB40D35D1515D2AB36003EE4B5580C5846B6BE74BFC41A663388
```

The order in my features manifest is the following

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="270999a6-d404-498a-83d4-3bab69d723c2" Scope="Web" Title="My Workflow WebFeatures">
  <ElementManifests>
    ...
    ...
    <ElementManifest Location="A\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="B\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Yet I still get the following error

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The parent content type specified by the content type identifier 0x01080100B98211051B3409DB40D35D1515D2AB36 does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your content type "A" have the parameter "Inherits=TRUE", if not the child cannot find it.